# Setting Dataframe Value based on idx Series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Given the Dataframe `df`:

```
A       B       C
0.10    0.83    0.07
0.40    0.30    0.30
0.70    0.17    0.13    
0.72    0.04    0.24    
0.15    0.07    0.78
```

And the Series `s`:

```
A    3
B    0
C    4
dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to easily set 
the `3` element of column `A`, 
the `0` element of column `B` & 
the `4` element of column `C` 
 without looping over the series?

Something in the vain of:

```
df.loc[s] = 'spam'
```

(but this sets the entire rows)

The desired output would be:

```
A       B       C
0.10    spam    0.07
0.40    0.30    0.30
0.70    0.17    0.13    
spam    0.04    0.24    
0.15    0.07    spam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let s be the series defined above.

Then, we first set the value to `np.nan` in the underlying array, and then assign `'spam'`.

```
df.values[s.values, np.arange(s.size)] = np.nan # this modifies the dataframe in-place
df.fillna('spam', inplace=True)
```

outputs:

```
      A     B     C
0   0.1  spam  0.07
1   0.4   0.3   0.3
2   0.7  0.17  0.13
3  spam  0.04  0.24
4  0.15  0.07  spam
```

Comment: This is giving me the error `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.

Comment: Note that assigning directly to `df.values` is dangerous. It's [not guaranteed to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376520/9209546) as it is often a copy and may raise errors. The fact it works on this occasion should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. Both require converting your data to `object` type in order to assign strings to previously `float` series.

### Option 1: numpy

This requires you to input coordinates via an integer array or, as here, a list of tuples.

```
import numpy as np

# convert to numpy object array
vals = df.values.astype(object)

# transform coordinates
coords = [(3, 0), (0, 1), (4, 2)]
idx = np.r_[coords].T

# apply indices
vals[idx[0], idx[1]] = 'spam'

# create new dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

print(res)

      A     B     C
0   0.1  spam  0.07
1   0.4   0.3   0.3
2   0.7  0.17  0.13
3  spam  0.04  0.24
4  0.15  0.07  spam
```

### Option 2: pd.DataFrame.at

A non-vectorised, but more straightforward, solution is to use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) in a `for` loop:

```
coords = [(3, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (4, 'C')]

df = df.astype(object)

for row, col in coords:
    df.at[row, col] = 'spam'

print(df)

      A     B     C
0   0.1  spam  0.07
1   0.4   0.3   0.3
2   0.7  0.17  0.13
3  spam  0.04  0.24
4  0.15  0.07  spam
```